# C++ Polymorphism issues. Something to do with _vfptr

Tags: c++, polymorphism, glut, shapes, vptr

I am trying to create a program that has the user click twice on the screen and a rectangle is drawn according to what was clicked.

Right now all I am trying to do is set my classes up to be able to correctly draw a rectangle manually without worrying about where the user clicks.

Eventually my program will be able to draw stuff like circles and triangles so I decided to use Polymorphism and have each shape type (i.e. `Rectangle`) be its own class that inherits from a class called `Shapes`.

I then have a class called `Game` which holds a `Shapes` object.

Shapes.h

```
#ifndef _shapes_h_
#define _shapes_h_
#include <vector>
#include "glut.h"

class Shapes
{
public:
    void DrawAll() const;
    void Add(Shapes * shape);
    virtual void Draw() const {}

protected:   
    std::vector<Shapes *> mShapes;
};

#endif
```

Shapes.cpp

```
#include "Shapes.h"
#include <iostream>

void Shapes::DrawAll() const
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < mShapes.size(); i++)
    {
        mShapes[i]->Draw();
    }
}

void Shapes::Add(Shapes * shape)
{
    mShapes.push_back(shape);
}
```

Rectangle.h

```
#ifndef _rectangle_h_
#define _rectangle_h_
#include "Shapes.h"

class Rectangle : public Shapes
{
public:
    Rectangle(std::vector<int> p1, std::vector<int> p2);
    void Draw() const;

private:
    std::vector<int> mP1;
    std::vector<int> mP2;
};

#endif
```

Rectangle.cpp

```
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include <iostream>

Rectangle::Rectangle(std::vector<int> p1, std::vector<int> p2)
{
    mP1 = p1;
    mP2 = p2;
}


void Rectangle::Draw() const
{
    std::cout << "Draw Me " << std::endl;
    glColor3d(0, 0, 0);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2d(mP1[0], mP1[1]);
    glVertex2d(mP2[0], mP1[1]);
    glVertex2d(mP2[0], mP2[1]);
    glVertex2d(mP1[0], mP2[1]);
    glEnd();
}
```

Game.h

```
#ifndef _game_h_
#define _game_h_

#include <vector>
#include "Shapes.h"

class Game
{
public:
    void Click(int x, int y);
    void Draw();

private:    
    Shapes mTest;
};

#endif
```

The first Game.cpp below is coded in a way of what I am trying to do, but it throws me the error `Unhandled exception at 0x001AF742 in Shapes.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000001.` After looking into this, I've found that some __vfptr hidden pointer variable (that I think controls virtual stuff) gets set to 0 and causes memory issues.

Note, `Click()` only gets called when the mouse is pressed, `Draw()` is called anytime any type of event happens (e.i. mouse press, mouse release, key press, key release etc.) When the mouse is pressed, both events get called, but `Click()` gets called first.

Also, `mTest`is the variable that is the Shapes object.

Game.cpp: Doesn't Work

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include <iostream>

void Game::Click(int x, int y)
{     
    std::vector<int> p1;
    p1.push_back(200);
    p1.push_back(200);

    std::vector<int> p2;
    p2.push_back(250);
    p2.push_back(250);

    Rectangle rect(rp1, rp2);

    Shapes * rectangle = &rect;
    mTest.Add(rectangle);
}

void Game::Draw()
{       
    mTest.DrawAll();
}
```

However, what seems to baffle me is if I add a Shape Rectangle to `mTest` inside of the `Draw()` function right before I call `DrawAll()`, it works. However, I want to be able to create the Rectangle depending on where the User clicks, and this method wont allow that.

Game.cpp: Works

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include <iostream>

void Game::Click(int x, int y)
{     
}

void Game::Draw()
{
    std::vector<int> p1;
    p1.push_back(200);
    p1.push_back(200);

    std::vector<int> p2;
    p2.push_back(250);
    p2.push_back(250);

    Rectangle rect(rp1, rp2);

    Shapes * rectangle = &rect;
    mTest.Add(rectangle);
    mTest.DrawAll();
}
```

Comment: You have a dangling pointer in the first example, as soon as `Game::Click` returns `rect` no longer exists.

Comment: So what your saying is that `rect` gets destroyed when `Game::Click` ends, so when I added `rectangle` to `mTest`, it ends up pointing to nothing when the function ends. How could I get around this?

Comment: Make `mShapes` a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shapes>>`, this will make sure the class properly handles the lifetime of the shapes while still allowing them to be used polymorphically.

Comment: I've never heard of `unique_ptr` but I'll give it a try. This however means that I need to go through all my code an modify it to work with `uniqure_ptr`. This is fine except at the point where I do `Shapes * rectangle = &rect;` When I try to do `std::unique_ptr<Shapes> rectangle = &rect;` I get errors. How do I handle this expression when using the `unique_ptr`?

Comment: To be honest your design is a bit wonky, why would shapes be both a shape and a container? If you absolutely want to stick with this then one quick and dirty fix would be to replace `mTest.Add(rectangle);` with `mTest.Add(new Rectangle(rp1, rp2));` but this might cause stuff to leak if and when exceptions come into play.

Comment: I was thinking that it was weird using it as a container and a shape. I'm going to try holding the vector of different shapes inside the `Game` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Shapes class replace

```
std::vector<Shapes *> mShapes;
```

by

```
std::vector<std::shared_pointer<Shapes>> mShapes;
```

Than replace code

```
Rectangle rect(rp1, rp2);

Shapes * rectangle = &rect;
mTest.Add(rectangle);
```

by

```
mTest.Add(std::make_shared<Rectangle>(rp1, rp2));
```

And finally replace method definition

```
void Shapes::Add(Shapes * shape)
```

by

```
void Shapes::Add(std::shared_ptr<Shapes> shape)
```

It makes your code works.

Summary: If you need pointers, think about smart pointers (std::unique_ptr mentioned by @user657267 is smart pointer too). You can read about smart pointers in many places, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/106614/1091536) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279674.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). For better design, do not forget for design patterns.